# Android location discovery in WiFi

Tags: android, position, location

hi i am wondering about some issues about location discovery in android.
i know that some of these are basic and not only android specific but lets speak about android.

1) if 2 users are in the same wifi then in no gps exists will both's location manager think  that they are in the same exact location?
2)if there is no wifi no gps then the location manager of both users will think that they are in the same location based on the cell tower?
3)if 2 users are in the same wifi then in order to say who is where we must do wifi triangulation ?is there another way(no gps)? if the answer is yes then in order to do wifi triangulation we need a second wifi spot right?with only one wifi spot can we find the exact location of each user?
4)gps indoors will provide false data(if it will provide any) , right?
5)what is the best way to find the position of users indoors?
thanks

Comment: One question per question please ?

Comment: they are all in the same topic. basically i need to know about indoor tracking. From what i searched on the internet i have seen that  if you want accurate indoor tracking you cannot do it through gps, nor cellid. With wifi you need at least 3 wifi spots in order to triangulate. Are these accurate?

Comment: You can do that by configuring a LocationManager with good critera, permissions, and PROVIDER